# Submit form data with optional image upload

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that I want users to have the option to add text only, an image only or both.

If you look at the database table here:

[image]

- id:102 is when the entire form is filled out. (I get no errors)
- id:121 is when the title and description is filled out only. Notice the .ext is missing. (See fig
  1 for errors)
- id:122 is when an image is only uploaded. (I get no errors)

**Fig 1 errors:**

```
Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in D:\htdocs\site.com\classifieds\addlisting-test.php on line 26
Your Listing has been posted!

Warning: unlink(../images/users/lea47/classifieds/53bce4ccaa93d): No such file or directory in D:\htdocs\site.com\classifieds\addlisting-test.php on line 200
```

Line 26 is here in this block. I'll add a comment to show line 26:

```
$name       =   $_FILES['image']['name'];
$temp       =   $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$type       =   $_FILES['image']['type'];
$size       =   $_FILES['image']['size'];
$ext        =   strtolower(end(explode('.', $name)));
$size2      =   getimagesize($temp); //LINE 26!!!
$width  =   $size2[0];
$height     =   $size2[1];
$upload     =   uniqid();
```

If someone could help me get rid of the first warning I think it would take care of the unlink warning...Maybe

I'm thinking I need an if / else statement on the getimagesize, but to be honest it's got me totally confused on how to fix this issue.

**My Question:**

So what I'm asking is if someone could help me figure out how to submit text only. Without the Warning messages and leave the upload_images column blank while doing so. Similar to this photoshop mock up on id 123.

[image]

Also instead of dumping the entire script in here, because I'm resizing the images and the code is a little lengthy I added it to pastebin. You can find the link here.

[CODE LINK](http://pastebin.com/ugwsjyvC)

I would appreciate any solution. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a little change on your script-

Change

```
if (isset($_FILES['image'])) { // line : 17
```

To

```
if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
```

**[UPDATED-1]**

Can you do this?

```
$datatobeinserted = array();

if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    // If you have added any image on your form field then    
    // DO the all your work here and add image into the array

        $upload_image           =       $upload_image;
        $datatobeinserted['upload_image'] = str_replace("../images/users/".escape($user->data()->username)."/classifieds/", "", $upload_image);



    // with that you can skip image upload part if you have added only text

}


$datatobeinserted['userid']                 =       $user->data()->id;
$datatobeinserted['title']                  =       Input::get('title');
$datatobeinserted['posted']                 =       date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$datatobeinserted['description']            =       Input::get('description');

$insertdata = DB::getInstance()->insert('records', $datatobeinserted);
```

**[UPDATED-2]**

Sorry for delay-

I have checked your complete code and i found lots of `if else` and your text is not uploading because you have put all your insert code inside the `image_upload` block
there is no any other block for `insert`.

Check this i have some changes.

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/25tspPU9)

You should do this like this example:

```
<?php
   if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
   {
     // do your all image upload work here
      $datatobeinserted['image'] = $yourimagename // this should be after image upload
   }

   //Add all your data in array

    $datatobeinserted['userid']                 =       $user->data()->id;
    $datatobeinserted['title']                  =       Input::get('title');
    $datatobeinserted['posted']                 =       date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $datatobeinserted['description']            =       Input::get('description'); 
    $insertdata = DB::getInstance()->insert('records', $datatobeinserted);    



   if($insertedData)
    {
       echo "Added Successfully"
    } else {
      echo "Something went wrong"; 
    }
?>
```

Insert Query should not be inside any `if else`. And if you really want to that then you should check for both (Text && Image) should not be empty for `Insert Query`.

Hope now you can understand what i'm trying to say.

Thanks.

**[UPDATE-4]**

Here is how you can manage it all -

```
if(empty(Image name))
{
   //HERE YOU SHOULD FOR THE $_POST
   // check here for both text fields
   if(!empty($_POST['description']) && !empty($_POST['title'])
   {
      //put your all stuff here with insert query for text only
   }

} else if(!empty(Image name)) {
  // do your image stuff
}
```

Comment: That only allows me to fill out the entire form to get it to store the records in the database. I have to upload an image for it to work. 
I need it to work when only text is inserted.

When I only add text I get no errors, it just refreshes the page on submit.

Comment: @echo - Check my updated answer. may be this help you.

Comment: I tried it out and think I get what your saying, but didn't get it to work the first time. I'll keep trying though. That definitely helps. It super late hear and i'm extremely tired. I will try it out more in the morning. I appreciate your help. I'll let you know  if i get it working.

Comment: I have tried to do this as you suggested multiple times, but it seems to only upload the image to my directory and NO data gets stored in my database table. Could you explain in a little more detail? Thank you.

Comment: try to print `$datatobeinserted` before insert.. and see whats there and whats not? first with only text, second with only image, and third with both.. this will clear everything..

Comment: Image only:
Array
(
    [upload_image] => Lea-CL-53bd57a4dc0a0.jpeg
    [userid] => 154
    [title] => 
    [posted] => 2014-07-09 16:54:29
    [description] => 
)
/////////////////////////////


All Fields:
Array
(
    [upload_image] => Lea-CL-53bd57fbf33a6.jpeg
    [userid] => 154
    [title] => Test All Fields
    [posted] => 2014-07-09 16:55:56
    [description] => Test All Fields description
)
/////////////////////////////

Only text fields:
Nothing, It only refreshes the page..?
//////////////Just wont upload to database.

Comment: Maybe if you wouldn't mind. Could you take a look at this updated code and tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

I'm getting syntax errors at the bottom on line 172 , 179 and 183.

Here is the link to the new code:[Updated Code](http://pastebin.com/ZzAwn26s)

Comment: I'm also open to any other suggestions if anyone has an idea on how to get this to work. Thanks.

Comment: @echo - please check my updated answer. Hope this can solve your issue, and there are not `if` block for these `else` line - 172 , 179 and 183. So this is an `Syntax Error`. Please check my answer. thanks

Comment: I did everything as you said and if I do a print_r or var_dump on the variables it's returning the correct information, it's just not being added to the database and I'm not sure why. Could be the insert query..? Also using the new method

`if($insertdata)
    {
       echo "Added Successfully";
    } else {
      echo "Something went wrong"; 
    }`


It automatically echo's out "Something went wrong" On page load?

Since the info is being collected, do you think it's something wrong with the query? And don't be sorry on late replies back, you are doing me a favor here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57096/discussion-between-shail-paras-and-echo).